# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def read_texts():
  quotes = open("‪C:\\movie_quotes.txt")
  content_of_file = quotes.read()
  print(content_of_file)
  quotes.close()
```

**before running it this appears:
[appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Vw2.png)**

**I keep on running this code and this error appears:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\check_profanity.py", line 7, in <module>
read_texts()
File "C:\Python27\check_profanity.py", line 2, in read_texts
quotes = open("â€ªC:\\movie_quotes.txt")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaC:\\movie_quotes.txt'
```

i use python 2.7.14
please i need answers!!!

Comment: What are you using to compose your program? From the line in the stack trace, `quotes = open("â€ªC:\\movie_quotes.txt")`, it looks like it's using an encoding that it shouldn't.

Comment: looks like you have unsupported chars at the start of the name.

write the path yourself = don't copy it from elsewhere and check if it still happen

Comment: It's running perfectly on my system, just changed file path, cause I am using ubuntu.

Comment: Try typing out the same path. (Like @ddor254 mentioned, do not copy from elsewhere) I tried the same on my system and I got a stray `\u202a` in the beginning of the string. But when I typed it out, it was not present.

Comment: @ddor254 still the same

Comment: @Kevin i am sorry i don't understand i am really new to this. i think what you are talking about is the pic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invisible character in your code. Use a hex editor or hex dumper to see it:

```
$ echo 'open("C:\\' | hd
00000000  6f 70 65 6e 28 22 e2 80  aa 43 3a 5c 5c 0a        |open("...C:\\.|
```

The character in question is [`U+202a`, the left-to-right embedding character](http://graphemica.com/202A), encoded as UTF-8 as `e2 80 aa`.

Remove the character from your source code by deleting `("C:` and retyping it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using forward slashes instead.

```
open("‪C:/movie_quotes.txt")
```